# I have anchors in my code that work in FF but not Chrome

Tags: html, anchor

They are both in paragraph two that starts with "The gam is scheduled for". The link "Slips and mooring balls" should link to the heading further down the page that's called "Slips and Anchoring" and the link "hotel accommodations" should like to the heading further down the page that's called "Hotel Accommodations".

The two links to the two anchors work through Firefox inside out network and outside of it. But, the anchor links do not work through Google Chrome

[Link](https://ssca.clubexpress.com/content.aspx?page_id=22&club_id=710182&module_id=336949&actr=4)

Answer (score 2):

In order to jump to a section of the page, you need to use the `id` attribute on the target element, not the `name` attribute. Use of the latter was supported in previous versions of the HTML standard, but is now [considered obsolete](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html#a-constraints) and will not work consistently across browsers.

Also, you don't need to place an empty `a` tag at the location of your jump -- you can simply add an `id` attribute to the element you want to jump to.

---

### Good

Here's the simplest, but not best, way of changing the page to implement your desired functionality.

```
<strong id="SlipsandAnchoring">
  <span style="font-size: 18px;">
    Slips and Anchoring<br>
    <img .../>
  </span>
</strong>
```

---

### Better

The previous solution works, but isn't particularly accessible by users with impairments, especially those who use screen readers to navigate.

A quick compromise to help with this would be to break out the title into its own element, which screen readers can focus on. You can then wrap the section in a `div`, which helps convey the hierarchy of the page.

```
<div id="SlipsandAnchoring">
  <p style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">Slips and Anchoring</p>
  <img .../>
</div>
```

---

### Best

The best solution, however, would be to wrap each section of the page in a `section` tag. Sections group related content and are the preferred way to separate different parts of a page in HTML5.

Apart from being semantic best practice, section tags can be navigated to easily with screen readers, as the meaning of the tag is familiar to most software.

After doing this, you should also use header tags to indicate that the titles are significant landmarks on the page.

```css
section h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

section img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 202px;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section id="SlipsandAnchoring">
  <h4>Slips and Anchoring</h4>
  <img src="//s3.amazonaws.com/ClubExpressClubFiles/710182/graphics/St._Augustine_Sailboats_Anchored_Pixabay_1494285995.jpg" alt="St. Augustine Sailboats Anchored Pixabay">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Map your text like `<a name="SlipsandAnchoring">Slips and Anchoring</a>`